# loading json data How to show clustered bar charts in dynamic graphs

Tags: codeigniter, charts, amcharts

**Updated**

**Can you possible graphs value dynamic.
    Below code pass a static value but i get dynamic code graphs.
    Example: resultx get 3-4 subcategory i every time define graphs value.**

```
var processedChartData = resultx.map(function(rawDataElement) {
  var newDataElement = { "category": rawDataElement.category };
  rawDataElement.data.forEach(function(nestedElement, index) {
    newDataElement["value" + index] = nestedElement.value;
    newDataElement["subcategory" + index] = nestedElement.subcategory
  });
  return newDataElement;
});
```

---

```
AmCharts.makeChart(id, {
    "type": "serial",
    "theme": "light",
    "categoryField": "category",
    "rotate": false,
    "startDuration": 0,
    "categoryAxis": {
      "gridPosition": "start",
      "position": "left"
    },
    "graphs": [{
        "fillAlphas": 0.9,
        "lineAlpha": 0.2,
        "title": "2004",
        "type": "column",
      "balloonText": "[[subcategory0]]: [[value]]",
        "valueField": "value0"
    }, {
        "fillAlphas": 0.9,
        "lineAlpha": 0.2,
        "title": "2005",
        "type": "column",
      "balloonText": "[[subcategory1]]: [[value]]",
        "valueField": "value1"
    },
    {
        "fillAlphas": 0.9,
        "lineAlpha": 0.2,
        "title": "2005",
        "type": "column",
      "balloonText": "[[subcategory2]]: [[value]]",
        "valueField": "value2",
    }],
    "guides": [],
    "allLabels": [],
    "balloon": {},
    "titles": [],
    "dataProvider": processedChartData,
      "export": {
        "enabled":false
       }
  });
```

---

Original question:

Clustered bar charts Array inside key how to display multiple bar charts.

My json below:

```
[
      {
        "0":
        {
          "package_sold":"88",
          "vSectorName":"Meat"
        },
        "country":"France"
      },
      {
        "0":
        {
          "package_sold":"68",
          "vSectorName":"Meat"
        },
        "1":
        {
          "package_sold":"151",
          "vSectorName":"Poultry"
        },
        "country":"United Kingdom"
      }
    ]
```

How to show in graph dataProvider

Comment: Will you be more specific what exactly you want to achieve

Comment: Hi @AnilSamal  i'm edit my question please check

Answer (score 2):

AmCharts doesn't support nested JSON. You'll need to flatten your JSON into a single object so that your `valueFields` are distinct in each element of your array.

For example, this:

```
  {
    "0":
    {
      "package_sold":"68",
      "vSectorName":"Meat"
    },
    "1":
    {
      "package_sold":"151",
      "vSectorName":"Poultry"
    },
    "country":"United Kingdom"
  }
```

can be turned into this:

```
{
  "Meat_package_sold": 68,
  "Poultry_package_sold": 151,
  "country": "United Kingdom"
}
```

From there you can set your graph `valueField` to `"Meat_package_sold"` and `"Poultry_package_sold"`. I'm assuming your `categoryField` is `"country"`.

You'll either need to change your backend or write some some JS to remap your data to a format that AmCharts can recognize.

**Edit:** Here's a basic example that remaps your JSON data using JS:

```js
var rawData = [{
    "0": {
      "package_sold": "88",
      "vSectorName": "Meat"
    },
    "country": "France"
  },
  {
    "0": {
      "package_sold": "68",
      "vSectorName": "Meat"
    },
    "1": {
      "package_sold": "151",
      "vSectorName": "Poultry"
    },
    "country": "United Kingdom"
  }
]
var newData = [];
rawData.forEach(function(dataItem) {
  var newDataItem = {};
  Object.keys(dataItem).forEach(function(key) {
    if (typeof dataItem[key] === "object") {
      newDataItem[dataItem[key]["vSectorName"] + "_package_sold"] = dataItem[key]["package_sold"];
    } else {
      newDataItem[key] = dataItem[key];
    }
  });
  newData.push(newDataItem);
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(newData));
```

Demo of your chart using the correct JSON format:

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "categoryField": "country",
  "graphs": [{
      "fillAlphas": 0.8,
      "lineAlpha": 0.2,
      "type": "column",
      "valueField": "Meat_package_sold"
    },
    {
      "fillAlphas": 0.8,
      "lineAlpha": 0.2,
      "type": "column",
      "valueField": "Poultry_package_sold"
    }
  ],
  "dataProvider": [{
    "Meat_package_sold": 88,
    "country": "France",
  }, {
    "Meat_package_sold": 68,
    "Poultry_package_sold": 151,
    "country": "United Kingdom"
  }, {
    "Meat_package_sold": 120,
    "Poultry_package_sold": 110,
    "country": "Germany"
  }]
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>

<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: Hi @xorspark Your example is right but you pass static data.i'm not pass static data my data like this Array inside object then Array inside multiple object how to manage in graph please tell me.

Comment: @MayurPanchal - Like I said, your data can't be nested. My data being static doesn't change how your resulting data needs to be for AmCharts to recognize it. Modify your JSON output either on the server side or through JS before passing it to AmCharts so that is just a single array of non-nested objects, similar to my example. Arrays of arrays won't work in AmCharts.

Comment: Hi @xorspark work fine but one more question arise can you implement a dynamic graph in amcharts values means ajax call time 2-3 value then graph chart line 2-3 lines.

Comment: Sure you can, but you need to update your question to show how you're doing all of this. We're not mind readers and your original question is extremely sparse as is. Look at [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question and update your question with all the relevant details (provide an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that doesn't depend on a DB and mock your data)  so we can better assist you.

Comment: Reformat your code and post what your raw data looks like that you're trying to map. What is the end result you're trying to achieve? Do you want to make the sub categories their own graphs? What part of this do you need to be dynamic? The edited question is even more confusing than before.

Comment: I fixed your formatting and added the old question back so my original answer doesn't look out of place. Please provide more context as to what you're trying to make dynamic. A sample of your data, if it's different from the original question, would also help as well.

Comment: Hi @xorspark Please check above question in graphs part i'm using 3 array(json) but this parts how to dynamic manage. Means actually graphs value not every time 3 array.

Comment: Hi @xorspark  Yes i'm want to sub categories their own graphs can you possible?Their is not fix subcategory this fetch are in database every time not same.Graphs part need to be dynamic please help.

Comment: Can you post what your raw JSON actually looks like? It's not clear whether your subcategory is a value or another array from the map call and seeing a sample would be very helpful.

Comment: Hi @xorspark can you possible different different graph display when a subcategory display?

Comment: @MayurPanchal No, your JSON isn't there. The JSON in the original question doesn't match your map call. Post the one that corresponds to what the map call is parsing (the contents of `resultx`) or post a larger sample that shows your subcategories. Your JSON doesn't show sub categories and your `resultx.map` call doesn't even match what's inside. If you're referring to a drill down for subcategories, [see this example](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/drill-column-chart/).

Comment: The only other thing I can suggest is create your graphs array as you're parsing out your JSON into a compatible format and then pass that graphs array variable into makeChart when you're done. You clearly know what your data looks like so you can pull out whatever you need. The graphs objects look just like what's inside the makeChart definition. Again, without your full JSON that shows your subcategories, I can't give you an example.

Comment: Ok @xorspark let's try and then any query occur ask you.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is dynamic json data, but to show how to use and build I defined it so.
In actual, i use ajax to get json data and then building it dynamically.
Here I had Generate Graph,GLName against its opening for each month comparatively. hope it will helpful for all

```js
var resp=[
  {
    "MONTH_": "01",
    "MONTH_NAME": "JAN",
    "YEAR_": "2018",
    "GL_NAME": "CASH,FACTORY, SITE,OFFICE ",
    "GL_ID": "79,81,522,89",
    "OPENING": "606294,0,24851,170392",
    "RECEIPT": "1641300,40000,210850,82300",
    "PAYMENT": "2074921,103209,168893,40000",
    "CLOSING": "172673,149483,66808,0"
  },
  {
    "MONTH_": "02",
    "MONTH_NAME": "FEB",
    "YEAR_": "2018",
    "GL_NAME": " SITE,CASH,OFFICE ,FACTORY",
    "GL_ID": "81,79,522,89",
    "OPENING": "66808,172673,0,149483",
    "RECEIPT": "102650,40000,3479000,200000",
    "PAYMENT": "239379,168339,40000,3388527",
    "CLOSING": "-69921,0,181144,263146"
  },
  {
    "MONTH_": "03",
    "MONTH_NAME": "MAR",
    "YEAR_": "2018",
    "GL_NAME": "FACTORY,CASH,OFFICE , SITE",
    "GL_ID": "89,81,79,522",
    "OPENING": "181144,-69921,0,263146",
    "RECEIPT": "30000,40000,1943500,200000",
    "PAYMENT": "69242,1806551,18177",
    "CLOSING": "141902,400095,40000,111902"
  }
]
      
        var newChartDataArr = [];
        var colNameArr = [];
        var GLID = [];
        var amtArr = [];
        var newBarGraph = [];
        myJsonString1 = JSON.stringify(resp);
        var obj = JSON.parse(myJsonString1);
        var obj1 = resp[0];
        //spliting of GLName
        if (obj1.GL_NAME.toString().indexOf(',') != -1) {
            colNameArr = obj1.GL_NAME.split(',');
            GLID =obj1.GL_ID.split(',');
        } else {
            colNameArr.push(obj1.GL_NAME);
            GLID =obj1.GL_ID.split(',');
        }
        //Getting Month and Opening of GL
        $.each(resp, function (i, value) {
            var newObj = {}; 
            newObj['MONTH_NAME'] = value.MONTH_NAME+"-"+value.YEAR_;
            $.each(value, function (k, v) {
                if (k == 'OPENING') {
                    for (var i = 0; i < colNameArr.length; i++) {
                        if (v.toString().indexOf(',') != -1) {
                            newObj[colNameArr[i]] = parseFloat(v.split(',')[i]);
                        } else {
                            newObj[colNameArr[i]] = parseFloat(v);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            newChartDataArr.push(newObj); //GL with Opening
        });
        for (var i = 0; i < colNameArr.length; i++) {
            let graph = {};
            graph["id"] = "v-"+GLID[i];
            graph["balloonText"] = colNameArr[i] + "  [[category]] Amount:[[value]]",
            graph["title"] = colNameArr[i];
            graph["valueField"] = colNameArr[i];
            graph["fillAlphas"] = 0.8;
            graph["lineAlpha"] = 0.2;
            graph["type"] = "column";
            newBarGraph.push(graph);
        }
        chart = AmCharts.makeChart("Monthdiv", {
            "type": "serial",
            "theme": "light",
            "categoryField": "MONTH_NAME",
            "startDuration": 1,
            "trendLines": [],
            "legend": {
             "position": "bottom",
             "maxColumns": 2,
                "useGraphSettings": true
            },
            "depth3D": 10,
            "angle": 60,
            "graphs": newBarGraph,
            "guides": [],
            "valueAxes": [
                {
                  "position": "left",
                     "title": "Opening"
                }
            ],
            "categoryAxis": {
              "gridPosition": "start",
                 "labelRotation": 90,
                 "title": "Months"
            },
            "allLabels": [],
            "balloon": {},
            "titles": [{
                "text":"Monthly Sale"
            }],
            "dataProvider": newChartDataArr,
            "export": {
                "enabled": true
            },
            "listeners": [{
                "event": "clickGraphItem",
                "method": function (event) {
                  var gl_ID=(event.item.graph.id).slice(2);
                  var month = (event.item.category).slice(0, 3);
                  var calender = ['JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC'];
                  var monthVal = calender.indexOf(month) + 1;
                  var year = (event.item.category).slice(4, 8);
                  $("#fromDate").val("01/" + monthVal + "/" + year);
                  $("#toDate").val("30/" + monthVal + "/" + year);
                  Daliy(gl_ID,event.item.category);
                  showSummary();
                }
              }]
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Resources -->
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-12" id="Monthdiv" style="height: 370px;">
```